# Implementing autonomous NAT to NAT communication in Python

Tags: implementation, p2p, firewall, nat

I had been searching for a while for a way to perform peer-to-peer communication between two hosts behind NATs, when I stumbled across this: http://samy.pl/chownat/

I plan to try and implement the basic outline that is mentioned in the above page under the section "How's It Work".

My question is, what does he mean by "Machine A sends UDP packets to Machine B"? Does Machine A send packets to the globally visible IP address / router address of Machine B?
Also, will simply sending endless UDP packet streams from both sides result in an established connection?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understood:

Machine A sends UDP packets to Machine B's NAT which are expected to be dropped. Machine B sends UDP packets to Machine A's NAT which are likely to be dropped. Machine B's NAT thinks that UDP packets from Machine A are in reply to Machine B's UDP packets and sends it to Machine B. Machine B responds with UDP to the Machine A for handshake and will not be dropped as Machine A's NAT also thinks is in reply to Machine A's UDP packets. UDP communication established!